# Is there a generalization of Sturm-Liouville theory to higher order ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

In informal terms, the Sturm-Liouville theorem states that if you have a second-order ODE with certain homogeneous boundary conditions on the interval [a,b] in Sturm-Liouville form, and if you manage to find the set of eigenfunctions, g(x), that solve both the ODE and boundary conditions, then if you have an arbitrary function f(x) on that same interval you should be able to write f(x) as a linear combination of all your g(x)s. The constants can be found using the abbreviated formula <f,g>/<g,g>. My questions is this: is there any generalization of Sturm-Liouville theory to 3rd order linear ODEs or 4th or nth order? Do the same principles for second-order ODEs that I discussed above have some sort of analogue in higher order ODEs? Because it seems like any time I see discussion of Sturm-Liouville theory, it is always invoked in the context of second-order ODEs.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it's worth noting that a higher-order equation can, through the introduction of variables for the derivatives, be turned into a first-order system of ODE's.  I don't know of any Sturm Liouville theory for these, but they are studied extensively (through equilibrium points, Lyapunov functions, etc etc).  Strogatz is the standard reference on these.

Comment: Dunford and Schwartz deals with higher order, even-order self-adjoint ODEs. It gets messy, but everything works out just fine, and is a natural generalization of the 2-nd order case, but requires matrices and vector solutions.